# How to parse nested items with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse this website: https://www.scutify.com/stocks.html
I think because of the problems with frames (I'm new to HTML), the stocks (such as 1-800-Flowers) did not show up when I use BeautifulSoup to parse the html link. So I then saved it as a htm file and can now see the stocks

The htm file looks like

```
<title>Stocks/ETFs Listing - US, Canadian, UK, Australian and Indian Stocks on Scutify</title> 
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="Listing of US, Canadian, UK, Australian and Indian Stocks and ETFs available on Scutify"> 
<meta name="keywords"  
<ul class="company-list list-group" id="us-list">
 <li class="list-group-item">
   <a href="https://www.scutify.com/company.aspx?ticker=FLWS">1-800-Flowers.Com Inc - (FLWS)</a></li>
 <li class="list-group-item">
   <a href="https://www.scutify.com/company.aspx?ticker=FOX">21st Century Fox Inc - (FOX)</a></li>
....
```

I tried the script below

```
downloadedfile = "C:/Users/vwxyz/Downloads/Stocks_ETFs.htm"
htm = open(downloadedfile,'r')
soup = BeautifulSoup(htm)
stocklist = soup.find("ul",class_= "company-list list-group")
print(stocklist)
```

However, it then prints out a gigantic bunch of text. I just want a list of the stocks, that is

```
FLWS
FOX
...
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you show what you get back in stocklist?

Comment: how do you get your downloadfile.  If I can get it, I will look into your code

Comment: http://pastebin.com/QnWhDaby

Comment: I just went to https://www.scutify.com/stocks.html, then rightclick "save page as"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the items in the stock listing and extract the part in the parenthesis:

```
import re

soup = BeautifulSoup(htm, "html.parser")

pattern = re.compile(r"\(([A-Z]+)\)$")
for item in soup.select(".company-list .list-group-item"):
    match = pattern.search(item.get_text())
    if match:
         print(match.group(1))
```

where `\(([A-Z]+)\)$` would match an opening parenthesis followed by one or more upper-case letters (captured in a group), followed by a closing parenthesis at the end of the string.